# Attempting to adapt existing code that opens Excel file based on a single keyword in file name to instead use multiple keywords

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have built a model that analyses crypto currency performance, based on raw data downloaded from a web portal. To automate this process, I developed some VBA code that recognizes the downloaded file by going to my "Downloads" directory and selecting the most recent file that has the word "BITFINEX" in its name. My challenge is that some of the cryptos I am interested in do not have that particular keyword included in the filename. Some, for example, use "COINBASE" instead and others may use something else. Bottom line is that I need my macro to choose the most recent of multiple file that include BITFINEX, COINBASE and, say, 5 other names that are not yet defined (for these, there could just be place markers saying, AAA, BBB, CCC, DDD, EEE). I am guessing that there is some version of the "Or" function that is required, but that is unfortunately beyond my coding skills at this point. The code I have attached is for my existing model and works perfectly. Any assistance would be most appreciated.

```
Sub OpenCryptoWorkbook()

' loop through all workbooks in "Downloads" directory to find one with "BITFINEX" in its name
 Dim fname As Variant
 Dim MyPath As String
 Dim MyFile As String
 Dim LatestFile As String
 Dim LatestDate As Date
 Dim LMD As Date

 MyPath = "C:\Users\gsk\Downloads\"

 If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
 MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*BITFINEX*", vbNormal)
 If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then

 MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation

 Exit Sub

 End If

 Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
 LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

 If LMD > LatestDate Then

 LatestFile = MyFile
 LatestDate = LMD

 End If

 MyFile = Dir

 Loop

 Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub OpenCryptoWorkbook()

' loop through all workbooks in "Downloads" directory to find one with "BITFINEX" in its name
 Dim fname As Variant
 Dim MyPath As String
 Dim MyFile As String
 Dim LatestFile As String
 Dim LatestDate As Date
 Dim LMD As Date, e

 MyPath = "C:\Users\gsk\Downloads\"

 If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
 MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*", vbNormal)
 
 If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
     MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
     Exit Sub
 End If

 Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

     'use an array of possible file names
     For Each e In Array("COINBASE","BITFINEX","AAA","BBB") 'etc
         If UCase(MyFile) Like "*" & e & "*" Then 
             LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
             If LMD > LatestDate Then
                 LatestFile = MyFile
                 LatestDate = LMD
             End If
             Exit For 'no need to test more names
         End If
     Next e

     MyFile = Dir
 Loop

 Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a dream. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Open Most Recent Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub OpenMostRecent()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\gsk\Downloads\"
    Const KeyWordsList As String = "AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE"
    
    Dim KeyWords() As String: KeyWords = Split(KeyWordsList, ",")
    
    Dim cName As String, rName As String
    Dim cFDT As Date, rFDT As Date
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(KeyWords)
        cName = Dir(FolderPath & "*" & KeyWords(n) & "*")
'        Debug.Print KeyWords(n) & ":"
        Do Until Len(cName) = 0
            cFDT = FileDateTime(FolderPath & cName)
            If cFDT > rFDT Then
                rName = cName
                rFDT = cFDT
'                Debug.Print "Newer", cFDT, cName
'            Else
'                Debug.Print "Older", cFDT, cName
            End If
            cName = Dir
        Loop
    Next n
    
    If Len(rName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation, "No Files"
    Else
        Workbooks.Open FolderPath & rName
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting a Compile Error "Unexpected End Sub"

Comment: Copy the code into a new module and try again.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thank you!